# What percentage of published mathematics papers are correct?

Tags: soft-question, journals

As described in [Larcombe and Ridd](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0025326X17309955), estimates for the percentage of published papers found to be reliable or reproducible in sciences such as biomedical science, have been as low as 50%, 25% and even 11%.

My question is: In mathematics, what percentage of published papers are correct? (i.e. all new theorems presented in the paper are correct, and can thus be relied on). Have any studies been done? Perhaps estimates could be made, based on the number of published corrections?

Note that while the problem of finding the exact answer to this question, for some given set of journals, might be beyond our present capability, the question itself, is objective - not a matter of opinion.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but there is no way to answer. 1. A published correction does not mean that the paper is incorrect.  2. Not all authors care to publish corrections. And how do we know even that one, particular paper is correct? If many people read it carefully, this only suggests that it is probably correct. But most mathematical papers are not read by anyone.

Comment: A paper that is not reproducible need not be incorrect. The problem in experimental sciences might be more an issue of the publication system (publication bias) than any flaw within the papers that couldn't be reproduced. This clearly does not apply to mathematics. If the analysis in a mathematical paper is correct, it is reproducible. The rest is "primarily opinion-based" and I voted to close for that reason.

Comment: The answer must surely depend on what "correct" means.  If a key line in a lemma says "5+3+7  = 7+7 = 15", and the author subsequently uses only the consquence that 5+3+7 = 15, is the paper incorrect?

Comment: If you mean every claim and every step of the argument is correct, approximately 0% - the same as asking what percentage of computer programs in use have no bugs. If you mean that the main theorem is true, I think a clear majority. If you mean that the main theorem is true after minor modification, probably a vast majority.

Comment: Of course, we have no idea which percentage of papers in the sciences are correct, only the percentage that are reproducible. If someone succesfully reproduces a paper using the same method, they could be making the same mistake. A good analogue of replication in mathematics is when someone needs to prove a generalization of a result, so they read the paper and then adapt the argument to the new setting - i.e. they reproduce the argument based on the description in the paper. Attempts to do this often turn up some minor flaw in the original paper and occasionally turn up a serious flaw.

Comment: So I would say most papers in math are replicable in the sense that another mathematician, reading the papers carefully, and applying their own standard of rigor, would be able to prove (or convince themselves that they've proved) the same result.

Comment: Even assuming we can single out a "main theorem" of a paper, another question before correctness is to make sense of the statement of theorem. Are there several interpretations of its statement (to the reader)?...

Comment: Another issue with boiling this number down to a single percentage is that it'll depend what journals you sample from. There's a spectrum from top journals through to low-prestige but conscientious journals to low-quality but genuine journals through to completely fake pay-to-publish journals.  The 4th group clearly should be excluded, but it's hard to know where to draw the line.

Comment: " If you mean that the main theorem is true, I think a clear majority." I don't think the applicable word here is _true_ but rather *proven* (up to some standard of rigor).

Comment: It seems to me that "the number of published corrections" would not be a good measure (of something unquantifiable anyway, as others have said). Authors conscientious enough to publish corrrections, once found, would not be the greatest worry here (to me at least). Authors who might be completely oblivious of their errors ( for a variety of possible reasons) might make a bigger "contribution" here.

Comment: The good thing is that answer to this question is of no importance. Most of mathematics papers are not read by anyone. So why should anyone care whether they are correct or not?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko your statement puzzles me. Could you please elaborate? Do you mean that people mostly only glance through papers, without really reading? Or that most of the papers are not interesting to anyone apart from the author? Or that many papers are not interested even to the author and are only published to boost the publication list? (these are just my guesses, I don't have an opinion whether any of this is true, I am on an early stage of my career)

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko maybe that would make for a good question: how many math papers are not read by anyone (except by the author and the referee)?

Comment: @Michael Bachtold: Perhaps this is a good question, but I do not see how it can be possibly answered. And I am sure, that even the referees do not always read papers carefully. Reading mathematical papers is difficult and time consuming.

Comment: @erz: If they re-open the question I will elaborate. There is no enough space in the comments.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: You say that "Most of mathematics papers are not read by anyone" -- if that is true, isn't this a strong indication that there is a much too strong pressure on mathematicians to publish as much as possible? -- I mean, producing research output merely to inflate the body of published literature does likely more harm in terms of making it harder to spot important papers than that it advances the subject -- doesn't it?

Comment: @Stefan Kohl: you wrote: "there is a much too strong pressure... to publish..." Yes, it is. Yes, it makes harm.

Comment: Dear @M Dean: what is the basis for your extraordinarily confident statement "Note that while the problem of finding the exact answer to this question, for some given set of journals, might be beyond our present capability, the question itself, is objective - not a matter of opinion."? Do you have a background in mathematical logic? What do you mean by 'correct'?

Comment: In my opinion such a question would have to be asked much more cautiously and in 'second-order'-fashion, as it were, i.e. along the lines of 'Has there yet been any team of serious experts in  (1) mathematical logic, (2) philosophy, (3) psychology, (4) sociology, (5) some sizeable sample of active research mathematicians, (6) statistics, who all got together and thought about how to even ask such a question in a controlled scientifically meaningful fashion, and how to then measure the correctness of contemporary mathematical research?" I guess that that hasn't been done, and is hard to do.

Comment: "too strong pressure on mathematicians to publish" that does not follow. With less pressure, we'd avoid some unnecessary papers but also some beneficial papers. Moreover, the title or abstract might be enough in some papers (but you still have to write and publish the paper in order to publish the title and abstract). For example, a problem might be so evident that if you don't publish your solution, others spend time trying to solve it even if they don't need the result.

Answer (score 42):

This graph from [Errors and Corrections in Mathematics Literature](http://www.ams.org/notices/201304/rnoti-p418.pdf) indicates about 1.4% of published mathematics papers were followed by a correction.

[image]

> Corrections as percent of journal documents for subject areas of
>   Scopus. Three areas are shown both inclusive and exclusive of
>   interdisciplinary work. Comments are undercounted for journals that
>   choose to identify them as “letters”.

There is also a breakdown per mathematical topic:

[image]

> Error correction rates as percent of articles in the primary Mathematics Subject
>   Classifications from Zentralblatt. The eleven subjects in bold
>   contribute 51 percent of publications.

Comment: In this (well worth reading) paper, an  important  point is made: there is a significant  rift  between applied and pure mathematics, including   traditions, attitudes, methodology and so on. Because of this, it is not  reasonable to lump all of mathematics together, as all the statistics relevant to pure math will be buried in a much bigger applied pile.

Comment: By the way, I completely agree with the main point: even if any  expert knows that a certain paper is wrong, it is very unlikely for  them to do something about it. This makes life pretty hard for a beginner; good thing now we have MO.

Comment: I find it amusing that _Logic and foundations_ is near the top of the list.

Comment: This percentage is of little relevance, for plenty of reasons. Why the same weight for each paper? Also a paper can have 5 independent main theorems, one of which is false. And "followed by a correction", how is it counted? it can be mentioned as false in one or several papers by other authors, and then these statistics will most likely not take this into account. Finally, even for a given theorem, "false" has plenty of meanings, with different consequences, as was already said in the comments.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, @PeterHeinig , I changed "error rates" into "error correction rates" as you advised.

Comment: Are also "2. Comments" and "3. Other" in the table always corrections to results? Page 424 suggests that that is the case for "3. Other", but I'm not sure of even that.
Anyway, category theory, logic, abstract harmonic anal., number theory, algebraic geometry, etc. seem to have many more corrections than comp. sci., operations research, biology, ... even though applies papers are usually more often read. The perfectionists get into pure fields and find errors more often? The paper claimed that there is no reason to believe such selection, but I don't agree.