# Shing-Tung Yau's doubts about Perelman's proof

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, ho.history-overview, 3-manifolds, ricci-flow

[**EDITED to make the question more suitable for MO.  See [meta.mathoverflow.net](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5172/3106) for discussion about re-opening.**]

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigori_Perelman#Current_viewpoints), Shing-Tung Yau expressed some doubts about Perelman's proof of the Poincaré conjecture in his 2019 book *[The Shape of a Life](https://yalebooks.yale.edu/book/9780300235906/shape-life)*. Yau wrote

> "I am not certain that the proof is totally nailed down. … there are very few experts in the area of Ricci flow, and I have not yet met anyone who claims to have a complete understanding of the last, most difficult part of Perelman's proof … As far as I'm aware, no one has taken some of the techniques Perelman introduced toward the end of his paper and successfully used them to solve any other significant problem. This suggests to me that other mathematicians don't yet have full command of this work and its methodologies either."

To what extent are the doubts that Yau expressed well-founded?

---

Here is a fuller quotation of the relevant passage from Yau's book *The Shape of a Life* (pages 258–260).

> One problem I'm not actively working on is the Poincaré conjecture, as I'm happy to put the controversy surrounding it behind me. But I can't keep my mind from turning to that problem, upon occasion, and I still have some lingering doubts that—if expressed out loud—are likely to get me in trouble. Although it may be heresy for me to say this, I am not certain that the proof is totally nailed down.  I am convinced, as I've said many times before, that Perelman did brilliant work regarding the formation and structure of singularities in three-dimensional spaces—work that was indeed worthy of the Fields Medal he was awarded (but chose not to accept). Perelman built upon a foundation painstakingly laid down by Hamilton and carried us further along the path laid out by Poincaré than we've ever ventured before. About this I have no doubts, and for that, Perelman deserves tremendous credit. Yet, I still wonder how far his work involving Ricci flow "technology" has taken us. And I also can't keep from wondering whether another approach—making use of some of the minimal surface techniques I developed many years ago with Bill Meeks, Rich Schoen, and Leon Simon—might lend some clarity to the situation.
> In 2003, Perelman told Dana Mackenzie, a reporter for *Science* magazine, that it would be "premature" to make a public announcement regarding a proof of the geometrization and Poincaré conjectures until other experts in the field weighed in on the matter. Confirmation of this proof resided largely with outside "experts," given that Perelman receded almost completely from the mathematics scene, which is a great loss to the field. The thing is, there are very few experts in the area of Ricci flow, and I have not yet met anyone who claims to have a complete understanding of the last, most difficult part of Perelman's proof.
> In 2006 or thereabouts, a visiting mathematician who was knowledgeable about this area stopped by my Harvard office to reproach me for raising questions about Perelman's work. Yet he admitted, when I asked him, that he did not entirely grasp the latter part of Perelman's argument. That's no knock on him, as that admission puts him in a rather sizable group. In fact, I don't know whether anyone else, including Hamilton, has fully gotten it, and I'd put myself in that category as well. As far as I'm aware, no one has taken some of the techniques Perelman introduced toward the end of his paper and successfully used them to solve any other significant problem. This suggests to me that other mathematicians don't yet have full command of this work and its methodologies either.
> Hamilton, who's now in his seventies, has told me that it is still his dream to prove the Poincaré conjecture. That does not mean that he thinks Perelman did anything wrong. Hamilton, a truly independent spirit, is not one to follow in someone else's footsteps, nor would he be inclined to "connect the dots" of another's argument. He just may want to do it his own way and complete his life's work of the past three and a half decades.
> Nevertheless, that still leaves me with the sense that this situation is not unequivocally resolved, perhaps leaving theorems of incredibly broad sweep hanging in the balance. Expressing my doubts on this subject, I know from experience, is a politically fraught proposition. But for the sake of my own questions—and for mathematics as a whole—I'd still like to be more certain of where we stand. If that makes me a pariah, so be it. In the end I care more about mathematics—the path I chose to follow more than a half century ago—than I do about what others think of me.

Comment: You are a bit trolling here: if Yau said that in 2019, exactly what kind of answer do you expect to receive here? Why would you trust some (possibly anonymous) posters on a forum if you do not trust Yau?

Comment: @AlexM. Not all posters on MO are anonymous.  Perhaps the main concern is whether this question is likely to cause arguments.

Comment: One should make a distinction between Perelman's proof of the Poincare conjecture and his proof of the geometrisation conjecture.  For the former there are shortcuts that allow one to avoid the most difficult components of his arguments, which is presumably what Yau is alluding to here .  In any event the subject has progressed since 2019, see e.g., Bamler's survey at https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.12615

Comment: This question is all over the place. First is the ambiguity Terry mentioned. Second, the first paragraph strongly implies you're curious and trying to find out whether the Poincare conjecture is resolved, but the question you ask, which starts with the word "so", just asks about Perelman's proof.

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question (not trolling). Not clear why people are voting to close it.

Comment: @GHfromMO: I voted to close because the question is definitely not as deep as some overthinkers here like to believe. It is rather *"hey, I've heard that one of the million dollars questions has been solved, but smart guy 1 says that some part of the proof might be wrong, while smart guy 2 says that everything is fine; what do you, ppl, think about this, eh?"*. I'm surprised every time when I see how gullible the smartest people are.

Comment: I voted to close as my impression is this is not a serious question.   Cherry picking a comment from a Wikipedia page does not even reflect a balanced reading of that same Wikipedia page.   This isn't a serious question, it's Reddit trolling.

Comment: A better question might be: "are there known problems with Perelman's proof?" (my guess is that the answer would be "no". But that doesn't make the question into a bad question.)

Comment: There have been discussions on meta and before that on tea about whether questions about correctness of papers are appropriate to MO and the general consensus seemed to be vague questions asking if it is correct or not are generally not on topic but if you want to ask specific questions about specific parts of a paper that could potentially be on topic.

Comment: I find Yau's quote quite bizarre (he surely knows the authors of 3 detailed accounts of the full proof). To make things worse, the last part is seriously outdated, given papers by Kleiner and Lott on the orbifold geometrization and by Bamler and Kleiner on the generalized Smale conjecture

Comment: I don't remember precisely the date nor the name, but I do remember that a well-known american newspaper made its headline with an article claiming that Yau and two of his collaborators tried to approriate the proof of the Poincaré conjecture without giving proper credit to Perelman. The article also mentionned that the mathematical community remained very passive as the attempt to steal Perelman's credits for the proof was on its way. (Contnd)

Comment: Perelman even mentions this story in one of his letter to explain why he refused the Fields medal and the 1M prize. Since then Yau kept his honorary position in Harvard (which his very intriguing, to say the least) and some people stillbelieve Yau can have a fair opinion on Perelman 's work.

Comment: I personnally find this question perfectly accurate given the history of the mathematician who objects the in-details validity of Perelman 's proof.

Comment: Quote from the article : the "official" director of Yau's mathematical institue in Bejing says “Hamilton contributed over fifty per cent; the Russian, Perelman, about twenty-five per cent; and the Chinese, Yau, Zhu, and Cao et al., about thirty per cent.” see : https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2006/08/28/manifold-destiny

Comment: @Libli: This quote speaks volumes about Yau and why he is not on speaking terms with people advancing the theory of RF for the last 15 years. It does not make the current question on-topic for MO.

Comment: @MoisheKohan As someone familiar with many parts of Hamilton and Perelman's work but not an up-to-date expert in the field, it seems clear that there is a research community with somewhere on the order of five members, maybe fewer, who use and develop the most complicated parts of Perelman's work. As such, Yau's use of "no one" seems unjustified but his point seems easily adaptable. To me, it seems that many (even most) parts of Perelman's work are widely understood but that some parts are still obscure to the vast majority, which seems notable for such major work from 20 years ago

Comment: @QuartoBendir: Notable but not at all surprising. It takes a huge effort to get through the proof and, unless someone is willing to make research in RF their primary focus, the reward for time and energy spent is low. I spoke to one person who spend over a year on this, got through the end of the proof and told me afterward about regretting the time spent. (The person never published anything on RF.) In any case, none of it makes the OP an on-topic question for MO. If somebody has a question about particular details, they surely know how and whom to ask. Else, it's just an idle chatter.

Comment: To say the least, there are many Ricci flow experts who only understand some certain small parts of Perelman's second paper. Anyway, depending on the researcher's field there are two possible types of research-level questions, one about specific details and one about the existence of expert consensus. To me, and only speaking for myself, the latter question is rather complicated in the present case, and I find most responses to it rather superficial. That's just to say that I would benefit from a thoughtful answer to some version of this question, and that I've hoped for many years to read it!

Comment: I think this question is obviously on-topic for MO.  A prominent mathematician publicly raised doubts about an important proof, one that to a certain extent reached the media.  My impression is certainly that the consensus is that Yau is wrong, but it makes sense that someone would have that question, and it's reasonable to hope that experts in the area can weigh in.

Comment: The above quotes by Yau are from 2003 and 2006, before expositions of Perelman's work on the geometrization appeared. (Poincare's conjecture was accepted  earlier, hence the Fields medal in 2006). The quotes deal primarily with the matters of credit, not correctness. If Yau thought there is no proof of geometrization, he would have said so back then, and continued to spread the word, which has not been happening. A complete understanding of any major piece of mathematics is always reserved to selected few, those with enough ability, motivation, and time.

Comment: (cont) Clearly Perelman's proof withstood significant scrutiny by top people. Just watch online lectures by Morgan, Kleiner or Bamler, or read various surveys. And the proof's bits and pieces are digested by great many people. I say the proof of the geometrization is as safe as it can be. I don't see how this question contributes to understanding of the mathematical or historical matters.

Comment: @arsmath The trouble is how Yau is going about expressing his concerns. Had he simply said, "Certain parts of Perelman's argument should be explained better, digested by more experts, and applied to other problems," there would be no issue. Instead, he disingenuously claims to want to put controversy behind him, and then immediately phrases things in a way that *by his own admission* is controversial. As Igor Belegradek says, Yau relies on an anonymous quote from 2006 and is silent about more recent developments. This strikes me not as "caring about mathematics" but just courting controversy.

Comment: @TimothyChow: I see no reason to blame anyone. I suspect that during 2003-2006 most experts would not bet their lives that details in Perelman's proof can be filled. I recall an interview with Morgan right before ICM where he said something like "ask me later if everything works". I think the situation now (2021) is different. I have not heard of any substantive issues. Of course, Perelman's papers are extremely condensed, so there are great expository challenges. It is much easier to read other sources.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: are you sure the quote is from 2006? It seems to be from a book that was published in the last few years.

Comment: @SamHopkins: I am just going by the above quote starting from "In 2006 or thereabouts". Yau's book was published in 2010, I suppose publication takes a few years, so everything was written well before 2010.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Yau's book was published in 2019. Don't confuse this with Yau's other book, *The Shape of Inner Space*, which was published in 2010.

Comment: @TimothyChow: then I was confused about the date. In any case unless specific issues with the proof are pointed out, the discussion is an idle chat, which imo does not belong at MO, and again, I am not aware of any issues.

Comment: @TimothyChow I'm not trying to defend Yau, since the consensus is that he's wrong.  I am trying to defend the principle that asking the question is legitimate.  I don't see any way to interpret what happened here other than we as a community have decided to cover up any embarrassing fights.  Which, to my mind, is more embarrassing than the fight itself.

Comment: @arsmath: This is a badly asked question consisting of three ingredients: (1) a meaningless title ("accepted by whom?"), (2) long and rambling quotes from Yau that offer no specific criticism of Perelman's proof only laments on this and that, (3) the question "is Perelman's proof essentially immune to the remarks by Shing-Tung Yau?" which is again meaningless since Yau offered no specific criticism. If you can ask a better question, go ahead, maybe you will manage.

Comment: If this question were "Do Yau's criticisms hold water?", then we could have an answer by an expert, and accept it, and go home. As it stands, the question presupposes the correctness of the criticism, which people in the comments have rebutted. I would be perfectly happy for a rewording to something asking about Yau's statement, particularly in the title, and have this re-opened. Note that Tim Chow raised this question on meta: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/5172/4177

Comment: The answers to this revised question have borne-out my initial criticism.  If the OP had done some due diligence, there would have been no reason for the thread.  Typically we close threads for these reasons.  The only reason this thread is open is that it's sensationalist.

Comment: @RyanBudney I don't agree that everything in this thread can be discovered just by "due diligence." If someone with Yau's stature says something like this, it's not always easy to determine whether the criticisms are well-founded. Due diligence might turn up some references but won't reveal that the community as a whole rejects the suggestion that there might be a significant gap in the most difficult part of Perelman's argument. Now, I agree that Yau's remarks are sensationalist, but that's the main reason people are voting to *close* the thread, not the reason it's open.

Comment: I think there is no reason for the thread.  I came across these comments on Yau's Wikipedia page two years ago and never thought to elevate it to the status of a Math Overflow question.  It's simply his personal opinion as someone who does not work in the field and is not keeping up to date with the new developments.

Comment: I am inclined to agree that this is a bad question for mathoverflow, and that both answers at present (including my own) are unsatisfactory. If mathoverflow is intended to be about providing expert opinion and knowledge and not just about finding and quoting reliable sources, then I think the collection of comments and answers given here marks a failure. The only voice here which has any particular expertise in the relevant field of mathematics seems to be Yau himself.

Answer (score 32):

First, let me make some preliminary remarks.  We sometimes like to think that "being proved" is a black-and-white property, but in fact there are shades of gray.  At one extreme are things like the infinitude of the primes, whose proof every mathematician understands.  But then there are [results that are widely accepted but no proof has appeared](https://mathoverflow.net/q/357317).  Vladimir Voevodsky [has pointed out](https://www.ias.edu/ideas/2014/voevodsky-origins) that "a technical argument by a trusted author, which is hard to check and looks similar to arguments known to be correct, is hardly ever checked in detail," and that this practice can lead to false statements being erroneously accepted as proved; recognizing this point led Voevodsky to spend much of the later part of his career on computer verification of formal proofs.  Although the mathematical literature is generally very reliable, it is far from perfect; this point has been addressed in more detail in another MO question about [the extent of wrong papers in research mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/q/351640).  So in
vast majority of cases, "being proved" isn't about being 100% confident
that there is no error; it's about whether the proof has been sufficiently
scrutinized that the chances of a serious mistake are negligible.

Returning to Yau,
if you look carefully at what he is saying, you will see that, technically, he does *not* say that he thinks Perelman's proof is wrong, or that it has a serious gap, or even that there are parts of the proof that nobody understands.  He says only that *he* is not certain that the proof is totally nailed down, and that *he* has not met anyone who understands the most difficult part of the proof.  He also points out that if a powerful new idea is properly digested by the mathematical community then it usually leads to the solution of new problems, and that if this has not happened with the most difficult part of Perelman's proof then it probably means that this part of the proof deserves more study.

In principle, calling for the mathematical community to devote more time to studying an important and difficult proof in order to "nail it down" and acquire a "complete understanding" and a "full command of this work" is unobjectionable. In the past, I have heard colleagues say that the original work of various Fields Medalists—Hironaka and Freedman come to mind—was very difficult to understand and that  there was a need for the community to study and assimilate those groundbreaking ideas more thoroughly. In both the cases of Hironaka and Freedman, the community has indeed put in effort to study their work, and rich dividends have resulted, so this type of activity is definitely worth encouraging.  Note that this doesn't mean that the original proofs were wrong or had serious gaps; it just means that the proofs moved closer to the infinitely-many-primes ideal of universal understanding, and the chance of an unnoticed significant gap or error was driven down even closer to zero.

Unfortunately, Yau chose to phrase his remarks in a "politically fraught" manner that he knew would "get him in trouble."
He says things in a way that (probably intentionally)
gives many readers the impression
that he is casting doubt on the correctness and completeness of Perelman's proof (even though, as I said, technically he doesn't explicitly say that the proof is wrong or incomplete). The book appeared in 2019 but the most recent conversation he cites was from 2006.
He makes no mention of recent research in the area which
does in fact apply Perelman's ideas to solve new problems.

It should therefore not be surprising that the consensus of the mathematical community is that Yau's remarks do not pose any serious challenge to the conclusion that Perelman's proofs—especially of the Poincaré Conjecture, which involves fewer technicalities than the Geometrization Conjecture—are correct.  There were at least three separate efforts which came to this conclusion.  [Kleiner and Lott's detailed notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605667) say, regarding Perelman's original papers [51] and [52]:

> Regarding the proofs, the papers [51, 52] contain some incorrect statements and incomplete arguments, which we have attempted to point
> out to the reader. (Some of the mistakes
> in [51] were corrected in [52].) We did not find any serious problems, meaning problems
> that cannot be corrected using the methods introduced by Perelman.

Similarly, [Morgan and Tian](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607607) wrote:

> In this book we present a complete and detailed proof of the
> Poincaré Conjecture. … The arguments we give here are a detailed version of those that appear in Perelman’s three preprints.

There is also the  [account of Huai-Dong Cao and Xi-Ping Zhu](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612069), which Yau himself refereed.

On top of those three detailed accounts of Perelman's proof, there have been more recent developments.  [Terry Tao mentions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407914/shing-tung-yaus-doubts-about-perelmans-proof#comment1046102_407914) the [recent survey by Richard Bamler](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.12615). [Moishe Kohan mentions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407914/shing-tung-yaus-doubts-about-perelmans-proof#comment1046142_407914) Kleiner and Lott's [Geometrization of Three-Dimensional Orbifolds via Ricci Flow](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3733) and Bamler and Kleiner's [proof of the Generalized Smale Conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.06197).  So contrary to the impression you might form from what Yau said, the community is indeed continuing to milk Perelman's ideas and apply them to solving new problems.  If there are specific technical points which Yau thinks are obscure, I am sure that other researchers would be happy to address them if Yau were to spell them out explicitly.  Until then, there is no credible reason to doubt the fundamental correctness of Perelman's arguments.

Comment: @QuartoBendir I am prepared to tone down my remarks; can you point out more specifically what you think I should change? Remember, Yau himself admits that he is being controversial, so saying that he is being controversial does not by itself cast aspersions on him. Regarding community wiki, note that the comments are almost uniformly against Yau, so that is why I tried to capture some of that in my answer. But I agree that it is better to err on the side of neutrality if possible.

Comment: I found these remarks about Yao to be careful and measured.

Comment: @QuartoBendir It seems to be a fact, not disputed by either side, that Yau is not on good terms with much of the rest of the relevant community. To understand why the mathematical community at large rejects Yau's remarks, it seems that one needs to be aware of this tension. Otherwise, that rejection is mysterious. That's why I think that commenting on this tension is relevant to the answer. Why try to pretend there is no tension? Yau himself does not pretend. He admits his comments are "politically fraught" and will "get him in trouble."

Comment: @QuartoBendir I have rephrased that paragraph in a more neutral manner while keeping the essential content, in an attempt to partially address your concern.

Comment: Clearly enough my concerns aren't shared by others, I've deleted my previous comments

Comment: Could you add one more reference, which gives the 4th version of Perelman's proof of the Geometrization Conjecture: Bessières, Laurent (F-GREN-F); Besson, Gérard (F-GREN-F); Maillot, Sylvain (F-MONT2-IMM); Boileau, Michel (F-TOUL3-IM); Porti, Joan (E-BARA) Geometrisation of 3-manifolds. EMS Tracts in Mathematics, 13. European Mathematical Society (EMS), Zürich, 2010.  They use yet another approach (via simplicial volume)  for the final part of the proof. Or, if you prefer, I could do this too since the answer is CW.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Please feel free to add it yourself.

Answer (score 21):

The question is, unavoidably, somewhat ambiguous. Here are seven points, hopefully rather objective:

0. There are well-known expositions of Perelman's work by Cao & Zhu, Kleiner & Lott, and Morgan & Tian. Many parts also appear in Bennett Chow's series of six books on Ricci flow.
1. As also said in the wikipedia article linked to in the question, Morgan and Tian's exposition of Perelman's shortcut to the Poincaré conjecture contained an incorrectly computed evolution equation, not identified as such until 2015. (This is part of the "shortcut" argument alluded to by Terry Tao in his comment.)
2. As also said in the wikipedia article linked to in the question, Kleiner and Lott's exposition of Perelman's work used an incorrect statement of Hamilton's compactness theorem, in which completeness and local uniform curvature bounds are falsely said to imply completeness of the limit
3. The errors in #1-2 are of the type which could in principle lead to fatal problems; compactness arguments in particular are used at nearly every stage of the work.
4. The errors in #1-2 are strikingly elementary in relation to the complexity of the arguments.
5. It is common for mathematical papers to have mistakes of a similar nature, as widely acknowledged. See e.g. [Why doesn't mathematics collapse even though humans quite often make mistakes in their proofs?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338607/why-doesnt-mathematics-collapse-even-though-humans-quite-often-make-mistakes-in).
6. In the last ten years, seemingly the full range of Perelman's results have been extended and developed by Bamler, Kleiner, and Lott, and so Yau's "no one" sentence is not accurate. Kleiner and Lott's orbifold geometrization paper claims to give a new proof of standard geometrization differing from Perelman's in certain respects.
7. The part of Perelman's work to do with finite-time analysis (which I don't believe Yau is referring to) has been extended to higher dimensions by Brendle, and adapted to mean curvature flow by Brendle, Huisken, and Sinestrari, and others.

There is thus a timeline of Perelman publishing his work in 2002-2003, with careful expositions appearing 2003-2006, and potentially problematic errors identified and resolved in 2013 and 2015. To me, and especially given #4, this suggests that despite all of the attention given to Perelman's work (and claims for 10+ years from some people about how carefully it has been checked), a certain amount of humility is required in approaching the question. As such, Yau's first sentence (as stated) seems perfectly well-founded as a personal opinion, and his last two sentences become well-founded if changed to acknowledge the three mathematicians in #6. The question of whether three is curiously low, or reliable to external observers, is perhaps too subjective.

Ideally it would be possible for an expositor or researcher to reorganize the logic of some of Perelman's arguments and so to present them from a novel perspective. Of course this is a tall order, although one closely aligned with the accepted answer in the MO question linked to in #5. Something like this has been (for some time) very successfully accomplished, for instance, in Perelman's classification of shrinking Ricci solitons (although this is not one of the more demanding parts of the proof). Also, the very recent results on kappa solutions by Brendle, Daskalopoulos, and Sesum lends some conceptual/structural clarity to parts of Perelman's circle of results, although I haven't studied their proofs. However, Yau is explicitly not referring to these parts of the argument.

Comment: Since when is wikipedia considered as a valid source?

Comment: I'm only acknowledging it as already mentioned on the page linked to in the question. It's not a source.

Comment: What are in your opinion the least understood part of the proof (of the geometrization)? Here "least" refers to the number of people who digested the part. Also isn't there also https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2065 that treats an important special case?

Comment: Errors found in expositions of the proof is very different from errors found in the proof. In particular, a big source of confidence in the proof is the existence of multiple independent expositions, each of which has been worked on or read by however many people. For each individual exposition, the source of confidence is not there, so it's not surprising if there's an error.

Comment: In fact it's possible for finding and correcting an error in the exposition to increase our confidence in the proof, if we go back to the original and see there is some terse remark that the expositors were originally unable to interpret but upon reflection clearly refers to the error-fixing argument. If this happens (and I have no idea if it did in this case) it suggests the original author really was very careful and then didn't write all the details.

Comment: @RW In this case, Wikipedia provides excellent pointers to the relevant primary literature.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I couldn't personally say, since I have met too few people who have even made the attempt to read all of it.

Comment: @WillSawin Perelman's papers have their own errors, which is of course unremarkable (this is why I mentioned #5). So I suppose what you say doesn't apply, although I've never understood such analyses

Comment: @WillSawin Indeed, for the 2015 Morgan-Tian errata in https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00699 , the original paper of Perelman https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307245 did indeed contain "some terse remark that the expositors were originally unable to interpret but upon reflection clearly refers to the error-fixing argument"; see the second paragraph of the Morgan-Tian correction and the sentence after (3) in Perelman's paper (Morgan-Tian initially bounded the ... terms incorrectly by $O(k^2)$ but Perelman correctly asserted the bound of $O(k^2+k)$, which the Morgan-Tian correction verifies).